Find a $(X,\mathscr{A})$ and finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $\mu(X)=\nu(X)$ but $\{A\in\mathscr{A}:\mu(A)=\nu(A)\}$ not a sigma algebra
Problem
The Problem is to find a measurable space $(X,\mathscr{A})$ together with finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ that agree on the whole set $\mu(X)=\nu(X)$ but are so that the collection
\begin{align*}
\{A\in\mathscr{A}:\mu(A)=\nu(A)\}
\end{align*}
is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

My Attempt
Let
\begin{align*}
X=\{1,2,3,4\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{A}=\left\{\emptyset,X,\{1\},\{2,3,4\},\{2\},\{1,3,4\},\{3\},\{1,2,4\},\{4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\right\}. 
\end{align*}
Then, $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, because it contains $X$, it is closed under complementation, and it is closed under the formation of countable union. Define $\mu:\mathscr{A}\to[0,+\infty]$ by
\begin{align*}
\begin{alignedat}{16}
&\mu(\emptyset)=0,      &&\mu(X)=4,              &&                  &&                 \\
&\mu(\{1\})=1,          &&\mu(\{2\})=3,          &&\mu(\{3\})=0,     &&\mu(\{4\})=0,    \\
&\mu(\{2,3,4\})=3,\quad &&\mu(\{1,3,4\})=1,\quad &&\mu(\{1,2,4\})=4,\quad &&\mu(\{1,2,3\})=4,\\
&\mu(\{1,2\})=4,        &&\mu(\{1,3\})=1,   &&\mu(\{1,4\})=1,   &&                 \\
&\mu(\{3,4\})=0,   &&\mu(\{2,4\})=3,   &&\mu(\{2,3\})=3.   &&                 
\end{alignedat}
\end{align*}
Define $\nu:\mathscr{A}\to[0,+\infty]$ by
\begin{align*}
\begin{alignedat}{16}
&\nu(\emptyset)=0, &&\nu(X)=4,         &&                  &&                 \\
&\nu(\{1\})=2,     &&\nu(\{2\})=2,     &&\nu(\{3\})=0,     &&\nu(\{4\})=0,    \\
&\nu(\{2,3,4\})=2,\quad &&\nu(\{1,3,4\})=2,\quad &&\nu(\{1,2,4\})=4,\quad &&\nu(\{1,2,3\})=4,\\
&\nu(\{1,2\})=4,   &&\nu(\{1,3\})=2,   &&\nu(\{1,4\})=1,   &&                 \\
&\nu(\{3,4\})=0,   &&\nu(\{2,4\})=2,   &&\nu(\{2,3\})=3.   &&                 
\end{alignedat}
\end{align*}
Then, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$, because they are both countably additive for sequences of disjoint sets in $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mu(\emptyset)=\nu(\emptyset)=0$. We have that
\begin{align*}
\{A\in\mathscr{A}:\mu(A)=\nu(A)\}=\{\emptyset,X,\{3\},\{1,2,4\},\{4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}.
\end{align*}
This collection is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, because $\{2,3,4\}\notin\mathscr{A}$ but it is a countable union of elements in this collection.

Question
Could someone please help me check if my example is valid? In addition, is there a simpler solution to this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Reference
Measure Theory by Donald Cohn Section 1.6 Dynkin Classes Example 1.6.1.

Update
Thanks for @Zerox's checking. My example was wrong.

@Zerox Typo: $\nu({1})=2$. Sorry about that.

Then $\nu({1,4})$ should be $2$, not $1$. Same for $\nu({2,3})$. And then the corrected equally measured sets (which do not contain ${1,4}$ and ${2,3}$) do form a $\sigma-$algebra.

@Zerox Yeah, well, you are right.

I don't think X can be finite. I think you need to use some infinite sum to get the contradiction.

@Snake707 Honestly, the hint for this problem said $X$ can be a fairly small finite set.

A finite example can be $$X = \{1,2,3,4\} \\ \mu (\{1\})=\mu (\{3\})=0, \mu (\{2\})=\mu (\{4\})=1\\ \nu (\{1\})=\nu (\{3\})=1, \nu (\{2\})=\nu (\{4\})=0$$.
In this example, $\mu (X) = \nu (X) = 2, \mu (\{1,2\}) = \nu (\{1,2\}) = 1,\mu (\{2,3\}) = \nu (\{2,3\}) = 1$. But $\{2\} = \{1,2\} \cap \{2,3\}$ and $\mu (\{2\}) \ne \nu (\{2\})$.

That is very fine.

Neat! Thanks a lot!
